# Haskell pattern matching do expression compiler warning

Tags: haskell

the following code will fail (only) at run time

```
do {(x:xs) <- return "";return x}
```

with a `user error (Pattern match failure in do expression at ...`

Is there a way to enable compiler warnings for this kind of potential errors?

Knowing that some destructive pattern matching might fail , what's the best way to handle this in the general case.

Thank you

Comment: ``(x:xs) <- return ""`` tries to put ``""`` into ``(x:xs)``. ``""`` is a list (of chars) and ``(x:xs)`` pattern-matches any (nonempty) list, so the types fit and that's the reason the compiler is ok with it. The fact that the ``""`` list is empty (and therefore the pattern matching fails) is another thing. It's the same like calling ``head []`` which will, too, compile smoothly.

Comment: For your question about compiler warnings, [it seems](https://downloads.haskell.org/~ghc/7.0.4/docs/html/users_guide/options-sanity.html) indeed that there is no option for it. `-fwarn-incomplete-patterns` only checks function arguments, not the left-hand side of a `<-` or a binding.

Comment: A similar scenario: `foo = let Just x = Nothing in x`. This also only fails at run time.

Comment: What behaviour do you expect? Deciding whether the pattern is correct or not is undecidable in the general case. Also you can specify only a single pattern so it doesn't make any sense to make a warning about "incomplete patterns". Do you expect to receive such a warning for *every* use of a pattern in a `<-` binding? Also, you can redefine `fail` so pattern failure can be an expected thing that you are handling in the monad. In other words, I don't see how the compiler could produce warnings without producing *too many* warnings.

Comment: I would expect (=like to have) an equivalent of -fwarn-incomplete-patterns which works with DO.  And if it is not possible, can anybody help me understand why it is not possible (an example ?).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a `case` expression instead:

```
do
    case "" of
        []     -> undefined -- or whatever else you want to do
        (x:xs) -> return x
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: thank you, this is what it needs to be done in order to not fail at runtime. I am still surprised that there is no warning at compile time.